# Searching an array for an object property where the property may be the same in multiple objects - avoiding the same object being returned?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm creating this app in Angular but my issue is basically just a JavaScript one. I have two objects, `roles` and `contacts`.

`contacts` consists of email addresses and their corresponding "role" number.

`roles` simply maps the role number to a title.

I have a function, `getRole(email)` that uses `array.find` on `contacts` for a matching email and returns the role number. Then another `array.find` to match the role number with the role title. I have a table displaying it all.

The issue is that there can be the same email address for multiple roles. Using `this.contacts.findIndex(p => p.email === email)` just finds the first matching email. Therefore, all repeated emails are given the role of the first object found (so you'll see that all test@example.com addresses are showing "first" in the table).

I was able to solve this but I feel like the way in which I did so isn't a great solution. Basically, a copy of the `contacts` array is made, the copied array is searched, and splices out any object found after returning it. I feel like there's a cleaner and more efficient way to do this however, and I don't like needing to use an outside copied array.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebmcy2

Component (hard coded the contacts for the time being):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  roles = [
    { role: 1, title: 'first'},
    { role: 2, title: 'second'},
    { role: 3, title: 'third'},
    { role: 4, title: 'fourth'},
    { role: 5, title: 'fifth'},
  ];

  contacts = [
    { email: 'test@example.com', role: 1 },
    { email: 'test@example.com', role: 2 },
    { email: 'test@example.com', role: 3 },
    { email: 'dave@example.com', role: 4 },
    { email: 'test@example.com', role: 5 }
  ]

  tempContacts = this.contacts.concat();

  getRole(email) {
    // MY SOLUTION
    // if (this.tempContacts) {
    //   let contact = this.tempContacts.find(p => p.email === email);
    //   let contactIndex = this.tempContacts.findIndex(p => p.email === email);
    //   this.tempContacts.splice(contactIndex, 1);
    //   return this.roles.find(o => o.role === contact.role).title;
    // }

    let contact = this.contacts.find(p => p.email === email);
    let contactIndex = this.contacts.findIndex(p => p.email === email);
    return this.roles.find(o => o.role === contact.role).title;

  }
}
```

Template:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Role</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
    <td>{{ contact.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ getRole(contact.email) }}</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Output:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOqm9.png)

Comment: What should be returned if an email has more roles?

Comment: If the email is associated with multiple roles there should be separate rows per role, per email address. So emails can be listed multiple times on separate rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the role in the `contacts` array you're iterating over - `getRole` is actually getting the *title*. How about changing the function name to `getTitle`, and passing it the `role`? The role numbers aren't repeated, so this lets you avoid the duplicate email issue.

```
<td>{{ getTitle(contact.role) }}</td>
```

```
getTitle(role) {
  return this.roles.find(item => item.role === role).title;
}
```

To reduce the computational complexity from `O(n ^ 2)` to `O(n)`, create an object mapping roles to their titles in advance, instead of `.find`ing in the array on each iteration:

```
this.titlesByRole = {};
for (const { role, title } of this.roles) {
  this.titlesByRole[role] = title;
}
```

```
<td>{{ titlesByRole[contact.role] }}</td>
```